# Merge identical [vue-directives] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are basically three identical tags:

- [vuejs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs-directive)
- [vue-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-directives)
- [vue.js-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js-directives)

They are for the same topic. They are identical in every sense, just spelled differently. They create confusion for which tag to use and they create tag bloat.

All three of them are somewhat slow and don't have a lot of questions and merging them will just simplify things for people who search this topic.

<sub>IMO they are not even spelled correctly, what you want is `vue-directive`, but that is for people to decide since those three listed above were present and one I believe should be instead of them is not.</sub>

Comment: After a quick look, it seems like Vue.js tags mostly follow the syntax `vue-*`, so I agree with doing away with the `vuejs-` and `vue.js-` versions. I am, however, in favor of `vue-directives`, *plural*, since when [registering a directive locally](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#simplest-directive-example) in a Vue component, you use the `directives` option, not directive singular.

Comment: Though the global syntax is `Vue.directive()`, singular. That's an odd discrepancy lol

Answer (score 2):

I created the synonyms for the two tags, and kept [vue-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-directives) as the parent, even though [vuejs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs-directive) had a larger number of questions. As zcoop98 mentions in the comments, most of the vue tags use the `vue-` prefix rather than the `vuejs-` prefix. Therefore both the other tags are now synonyms of [vue-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-directives), that is:

[vuejs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs-directive) (× 85) → [vue-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-directives) (× 38)
[vue.js-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js-directives) (× 27) → [vue-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-directives) (× 38)

I'll merge them after a few days, if there's no issues with the synonym. The next step is to create a nice tag wiki for them.